Restarting keyboard driver without rebooting system
I have an issue where my keyboard stops functioning periodically after getting stuck on repeat keys. All keys become unresponsive until I reboot. This is a linux specific issue (never happens on windows partition) and i have given up waiting for a fix (have tried latest stable ubuntu 6.2 kernal).
What i would like to do is be able to restart the inbuilt keyboard driver to avoid rebooting the computer. I can do this via a USB keyboard, and i also have a bash script that detects the keyboard getting "stuck".
Running Linux Mint 21.3 Cinnamon (5.15.0-112-generic)
Thanks
I have seen other questions have success when using "sudo rmmod atkbd; sudo modprobe atkbd reset=1". However, i get the error "rmmod: ERROR: Module atkbd is builtin." so I assume this is no longer an option with recent kernels.
Is there an alternative way of restarting the keyboard driver without rebooting (ideally that works in Mint and Ubuntu)?

Try sudo rmmod usbhid; sleep 3; sudo modprobe usbhid; If it still doesn't work try hid instead of usbhid; If that still doesn't work, try this: https://askubuntu.com/a/661 or any other answer posted therein.

@ArtemS.Tashkinov Why do people post answers as comments instead of as answers? Do you understand the purpose of this website?

@Cerin I can't be sure that what I posted will work. The OP has a chance to confirm or deny it. If they confirm it, I can turn my comment into an answer. As for the purpose of this site, I have no idea what it is, nor am I bound by it. Unfortunately the OP has effectively disappeared, so whatever I posted and researched, was ultimately in vain.

@ArtemS.Tashkinov Lol, so that's a no, you don't understand the purpose of this site... No one can ever be sure their solution will work. Maybe he didn't respond because you didn't post an answer?

Since he didn't answer, we'll never know. He would have ignored my attempt of an answer just the same.

Similar issue. ctrl shft and alt keys stop working. Actually, they work fine, according to xev -events keyboard, just that keypresses of other keys are then blocked. e.g. upper-case C doesn't work, nor does ctrl-C. The rmmod/modprobe solution does nothing. The keyboard magically unsticks hours or a day later.
